# IOS 13.2.2 Incorrect Wifi password

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, ios

I have an iPhone with iOS 13.2.2. Until today, my wifi connection was totally normal. After I turned wifi off and back on again, it keeps saying "Incorrect WiFi password". I tried the following steps but still nothing.

- Reset my router.
- Made my wifi router open (no password). Then iPhone says "Unable to Connect".
- Reset network settings in my phone.
- Forgot the network and tried connecting again.
- Turned off the Location Service related wifi settings and wifi assist.
- Tried connecting to other routers but got the same messages.
- Turned on Airplane mode and switched back to wifi.
- Did a hard restart on my phone.
- Reset my phone using settings
- Reset my phone with iTunes. (finder in Catalina)

I am totally frustrated with this issue. Other android devices and my MacBook connects to my wifi without any issues. Please help if anyone can.

**UPDATE:**

I restored my iPhone from 13.2.2 to 13.2. But the issue still persists. Now I'm out of options.

Comment: for me, moving closer to routers fixes it.. Try it, I don't find it worth an answer.

Comment: @ankii yes it works, but I have to take my phone to closest position to the router (2 cm) to get connected? Did you experience this issue after the 13.2.2 update?

Comment: That is quite opposite of what a wireless should have been ;-). But it's my college Wi-Fi so, I just move to another router if it persists. Good luck for your personal one! I have iOS 12.4.

Comment: Has your iPhone been dropped, bent, or had any other type of physical damage? It doesn’t seem like it should be giving an incorrect passcode error if it was a hardware issue, but I wouldn’t want to rule out antenna damage just yet.

Comment: @RyDev No , it doesn't have even a single scratch. I bought a brand new device from an Authorised agent about 6 months back. 6 months Apple limited warranty remaining.

Comment: By connected to other routers, do you mean you connected to other networks at different locations, or you connected to other routers at (I’m assuming) your home?

Comment: @RyDev yes I tried with my both routers at home. They are from different networks.

Comment: Have you been able to connect to any networks anywhere else?

Comment: @RyDev yes, it connects to my office network and hotspots created by apple devices without any issue.

Comment: @DinethSenevirathne did you manage to resolve this issue? I have exactly the same problem, suddenly no connection with a single iPhone/Access Point combination. Other iPhones/Macs do connect without issue using the same Access Point and the iPhone does connect to other Access Points as well. Only when *very* close (few cm) it connects

Comment: My problem apparently is related to 2.4Ghz. The iPhone cannot connect to any access point that uses 2.4 only (unless the iPhone practically touches the access point). 5Ghz is no problem.

Comment: @floorish Hey, since my phone is under warranty, I took into the service centre (authorised reseller) and they replaced a new phone even without trying to repair it. Now I can connect to the same network without any issue.

Comment: @DinethSenevirathne Thanks! Doing the same right now (except they are trying to fix it...)